# How to build Webrtc ios for generic ios device?

Tags: ios, webrtc, ninja, apprtc

I have downloaded webrtc ios. I have built it for arm64. I have followed this way to build it.
`gn gen out/ios_64 --args='target_os="ios" target_cpu="arm64"'`
`ninja -C out/ios_64 AppRTCMobile`
But I have got no way to build it for generic device. I would appreciate your suggestion.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/tools_webrtc/ios/build_ios_libs.py you can build a fat library, which contains multiple CPU architectures.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this link:
https://medium.com/@atsakiridis/building-a-fat-webrtc-framework-on-ios-8610fffb2224
I got some errors in running `gn gen` command. I fixed it by commenting out the line "//webrtc/examples" in BUILD.gn under src folder.